# Importing part from a different assembly

Tags: c#, mef

**Approach**

I am employing MEF to create a plugin-nable, if you will, application. My MEF host has an `ILogger` which exposes `TraceMessage(string message)`. Class `Logger` implements `ILogger` and is decorated with an `Export` attribute so `Logger` looks like:

```
[Export(typeof (ILogger))]
public class Logger : ILogger
{ }
```

The idea being that the various plugins can be offered a central logger that they can write to. Thus, instantiation would be via `[Import]` attribue, for example:

```
[Export(typeof (ILogger))]
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public ICloudTrace CloudTrace
    {
        get { return _container.Resolve<ICloudTrace>(); }
    }

    public Logger()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
    }

    public void TraceMessage(string categoryName, string componentName, string message)
    {
        CloudTrace.TraceMessage(categoryName, componentName, message);
    }
}
```

And subsequently a log message would be written via `Logger.TraceMessage(string message)`.

**Problem**

However, this approach throws an `InvalidOperationException` in my host when its trying to resolve exports, with an error message `Sequence contains no matching element`.

Exports are resolved in `ResolveType(string commandType)` (where `commandType` is the command line parameter needed to execute relevant plugin). `ResolveType()` looks like:

```
public dynamic ResolveType(string commandType)
{
   try
   {
     return this.Container.GetExports<ICommand, ICommandMetaData>()
                .First(contract => contract.Metadata.CommandType.Equals(commandType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .Value;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e.message);
    }
}
```

I should mention that each plugin has an `Execute(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)` which is the entry point for the plugin and the class containing this method is decorated with     `[Export(typeof(ICommand))]  [ExportMetadata("CommandType","CommandLine Command string goes here")]` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. It sounds like it is unable to either find the part, or the metadata. Have you got an example `Command` and a call to `ResolveType`. Also, can you confirm you can see the part in the container? I would also employ the use of `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` to be more fault tollerant, and drop `dynamic` from the method signature, as you *know* that you will be returning an instance of `ICommand`.

Comment: Aha! It was a problem with the `CompositionContainer`. The `AssemblyCatalog` wasn't loading the `Logger` assembly! 
Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `CompositionContainer` construction. Currently, it just loads the plugin assembly specified in the command line instead of doing directory scan or loading currently executing assembly. This has been done for various reasons. So:

```
var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile: assemblyToLoad));
```

where `assemblyToLoad` is a string to the .dll file for the specific plugin. However, the logger is in the host so the host's assembly needs to be loaded. Thus:

```
var assemblyCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()),
                                           new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile: assemblyToLoad)));
```

fixes the issue. 
Thanks to @Matthew Abbott for pointing this out